# How to access an value in a dictionary which is a encased in a list inside a json file

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

The question may sound a bit confusing but I'm just trying to access an element inside a dictionary. The dictionary was initially enclosed in a list with its key being the string 'main'. This 'main' is part of a json file in this format:

```
        {"coord":{"lon":151.21,"lat":-33.87},
        "weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],
        "base":"stations",
        "main":{"temp":291.97,"feels_like":290.16,"temp_min":290.93,"temp_max":293.15,"pressure":1016,"humidity":56},
        "visibility":10000,
        "wind":{"speed":2.6,"deg":250},
        "clouds":{"all":83},
        "dt":1587639926,
        "sys":{"type":1,"id":9600,"country":"AU","sunrise":1587587012,"sunset":1587626585},
        "timezone":36000,"id":2147714,"name":"Sydney","cod":200}
```

This is the class where I'm parsing the json file into, placing each part of the json file into separate classes or strings.

```
public class coord
        {
            public double lon { get; set; }
            public double lat { get; set; }
        }

        public class weather
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string main { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string icon { get; set; }
        }

        public class main
        {
            public double temp { get; set; }
            public double temp_min {get; set;}
            public double temp_max { get; set; }
            public int pressure { get; set; }
            public int humidity { get; set; }
        }

        public class wind
        {
            public double speed { get; set; }
        }

        public class sys
        {
            public string country { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public coord coord { get; set; }
            public List<weather> weather { get; set; }
            public main main { get; set; }
            public wind wind { get; set; }
            public sys sys { get; set; }
            public string country {get; set;}
            public string name { get; set; }


        }
}
```

This is the code where I'm trying to **access the value of 'icon' in the 'main' section** but it's giving me an error: **Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'WeatherModel.Weather'**:

```
public static (string, string, double, string) LoadWeather(string city_a)
        {
            int cityId = obtain_Id(city_a);
            if (cityId != 0)
            {
                using (WebClient web = new WebClient())
                {
                    string json = new WebClient().DownloadString($"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id={cityId}&appid=67f9bc5970b49b875ccecec84f849300");


                    var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherModel.Root>(json);
                    //Trying to acquire the icon from the weather list

                    string icon = items.weather[0]["icon"];
                    string url = $"http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{icon}@2x.png";
                    string city = string.Format($"{items.name}");
                    string country = string.Format($"{items.sys.country}");
                    double temp = items.main.temp - 276;

                    //city = cityName;
                    //country = countryName;
                    //temp = temperature;
                    return (city, country, temp, url);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return ("0", "0", 0.0, "0");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `List<weather>` collection to store deserialized `weather` and weather is an object, So you should get `icon` property like this:

```
string icon = items.weather[0].icon;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you deserialize the json object into a Root instance, each field is deserialized as well. The "weather" field is in deed deserialized in a List instance, but here the items of the list are of type 'weather', with 'weather' being a class that does not implement the IDictionary object. 
The items of the list are not dictionaries but instances of the class weather.

You should try

`items.weather[0].icon`